# how to query the outgoing paths in a junction using google api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are trying to implement a Google Traffic like software which automatically guide our vehicle towards a destination in the least congested path. In our concept we have to determine what are the junctions and the out going paths of that junction leading to.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps API does not make the road network available except through the directions service.

Your proposed use is against the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) 10.2.c

> 10.2 Restrictions on the Types of Applications that You are Permitted to Build with the Maps API(s)
>   (c) No Navigation, Autonomous Vehicle Control, or Enterprise Applications. You must not use the Service or Content 
>   with any products, systems, or applications for or in connection with any of the following:
>
> (i) real time navigation or route guidance, including but not limited to turn-by-turn route guidance that is 
>   synchronized to the position of a user's sensor-enabled device.
>
> (ii) any systems or functions for automatic or autonomous control of vehicle behavior; or